Still Have Result "CREATE PACKAGE" in SQL Statement for Assest Unified Auditing Oracle 19C
I followed CIS Recomendation for Unified Auditing to add audit option CREATE PACKAGE in audit policy CIS_UNIFIED_AUDIT_POLICY.
I already created it and enabled it, here is the capture :


But, after I assessed again using SQL Statement from CIS, it shows the result as captured below :

CIS state Lack of results implies compliance if we execute SQL Statement above.
My Database still have a result of CREATE PACKAGE when the SQL Statement above is executed and it means Not Compliance.
I have already  been searching for this, but not found the solution, really appreciate detail solution for this case.

Please do Not post pictures but text
